# Is there a verb describing someone on his elbows and buttocks, struggling to escape?

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to describe a scene where a man wakes up and is scared by something in front of him. He's in a lying/propped-up position, and he tries to move away from the object. All I could think of is "scram" or "thrash", but there aren't many examples where either of these words is used in the context "He was on his elbows trying to ____ away from the object". Is there a better verb to describe this motion? Thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: I think I've heard "butt crawl" used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ***scoot***

> He was on his elbows trying to ***scoot*** away from the object.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scoot) defines it as:

> 2 :  to slide especially while seated

Here are some examples of usage:

> I **scooted** backwards, still on my butt and lower back
>   <sub><sup>[Laurell K. Hamilton's Anita Blake, Vampire Hunter](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9THRdNrPKgC&pg=PT417&dq=%22scooted+backwards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8Uf6VPieJYKWNqyHgrAE&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBw)</sup></sub>

and

> [Olig'] tripped and fell over, landing hard on his back in the middle of the road. [...] and Olig', fearing for his life, **scooted** backwards like *jisduh*, the crawdad.
>   <sub><sup>[Robert J. Conley's The Peace Chief: A Novel of the Real People](https://books.google.com/books?id=YfhhY0GZ5qEC&pg=PT32&dq=%22scooted+backwards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8Uf6VPieJYKWNqyHgrAE&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22scooted%20backwards%22&f=false)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew I had seen this expression somewhere and I was thinking hard about a word starts with a "s" or "th" sound... This is exactly the word I'm looking for :DDD

Answer (score 2):

What about **"scuttling like a crab"** from the comments above?
3/4 credit to Oldcat

Comment: It would be a bit to long to fit in the context... but that's a expressive way of discribing this scene too :D Thanks!

Comment: I still think that even "scuttle" will give you more of a hurried spidery escape feel. "Scoot" feels to me like a single motion thing, [scoot over] (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scoot+over)

Comment: And OP wouldn't be using "like a crab", just "scuttled, scuttling"

Comment: @LittleEva ummm, Old People?

Comment: I just don't know what OP means here, and it's the second time I'm seeing it today, so enough with that...

Comment: OP = **O**riginal **P**ost or **O**riginal **P**ost*er*  = the question or the person who "posted" that question. :-)

Comment: I've started to think about the differences between "scoot" and "scuttle" ...Much thanks to @LittleEva and @ joeav !!

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't specific to the position you discribe, "**scrabble** away from the object" is the word that came to mind.  D

Comment: this got me thinking about "crab walk", or something like that. One of few expressions I know in German - krebsgang

Comment: Yes..."scuttling like a crab" or some such.

Comment: Thanks you! "Scrabble" reminds me more of someone on all fours or nearly trip over while escaping...  A plausible choice indeed XD